# jQuery / Ajax: How to call function on targeted page after redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, redirect, location

I am new to Ajax and programming in general and hope someone can help me with this.

I am using the following on a login page. 
This is used to register new users and will automatically forward them to an index page if their registration was successfully.

So far everything works as intended. 
**How can I call a jQuery function on the targeted index page from this or after that ?**
What I am trying to do is to show the user an alert telling them they were automatically logged in after the successful registration - so **this alert should only show up on the index page if someone gets redirected there from the login page**.

I could extend the below link to pass a variable (e.g. "`&origin=login`") and then use PHP to deal with that on the index page but that seems to be a large workaround and I was wondering if this could be achieved easier using Ajax.

I did some research and found some references to Ajax but no clear guideline for that.
Can someone help me with this ?

**My Ajax (in jQuery):**

```
case 'registration successful':     
    $.ajax({        
        type: "post",   
        url: "ajax.php",
        cache: "false",
        data: {
            node: 'loginUser',
            email: email,
            pass: pass
        },
        success: function(data){
            // redirect to index page
            window.location.href = baseURL + '/index.php?lang=' + selectedLang;
            // after the redirect I would like to show an alert on the targeted index page
        }
    });
    break;
```

Many thanks in advance, 
Mike

Comment: why not add an alert before window.location.href ?

Comment: Thanks. In that case I would need to wait with the redirect until someone closes the alert. How would I do that ? I was thinking of that before as well but since I am using custom modals for my alerts (and the modals are used on different pages) this seemed tricky to me as well.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao: Thanks for this. I am new to JS. Could you explain what you mean by "localStorage" and how this can be used ?

Comment: try add an alert inside success callback function , before your window.location.href and try it in action :)

Comment: @jameshwartlopez: Thanks. I can't use this approach on my current page. Please see my updated comment above.

Comment: ok maybe GuruprasadRao's suggestion is appropriate to what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly you can make use of `localStorage` to display `alert` after redirecting as one below:

```
$.ajax({        
        type: "post",   
        url: "ajax.php",
        cache: "false",
        data: {
            node: 'loginUser',
            email: email,
            pass: pass
        },
        success: function(data){
            //set a localStorage item
            localStorage.setItem('showAlert','true');
            // redirect to index page
            window.location.href = baseURL + '/index.php?lang=' + selectedLang;
            // after the redirect I would like to show an alert on the targeted index page
        }
});
```

and in your `index` page write below code in `script` tag or in any loaded`js` file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var showalert=localStorage.getItem('showAlert');
    if(showalert==='true')
    {
          //show the alert
          localStorage.setItem('showAlert','false'); //set its value back to false;
    }
});
```

A bit explanation about <kbd>**`localStorage`**</kbd>

> - **It stores data with no expiration date.**
> - **Local storage is more secure, and large amounts of data can be stored
>     locally, without affecting website performance.**

---

**UPDATE**

For your current requirement `sessionStorage` might suit well as you want to store the data only when the user logs it and want to clear it when he logs out. The usage is similar to `localStorage`, instead of `localStorage.getItem` or `localStorage.setItem` you can use `sessionStorage.setItem` or `sessionStorage.getItem`

So what is this `sessionStorage`

> **The sessionStorage object exists as a property of the window object in
>   supporting browsers (currently Firefox 3+, Safari 4+, and Internet
>   Explorer 8+). You can place data onto the sessionStorage object and
>   that data persists for as long as that window (or tab) is open. Even
>   if you navigate away from the page that stored the data and then
>   navigate back, the data saved to sessionStorage is still available.
>   Any data stored in sessionStorage is tied to the protocol, hostname,
>   and port of the page that saved the information and only pages sharing
>   the same protocol, hostname, and port can access that data later.**

You can read more about `sessionStorage` **[here](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/07/21/introduction-to-sessionstorage/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot - that's exactly what I was looking for here ! Never heard of it before. :) Will play around with it but this should do the trick. Thanks again !

Comment: Anytime.. Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: Thanks. After reading about this I think I could even use "window.sessionStorage" in this case. Not sure if that makes a big difference but I wouldn't need it after the session so this sounds enough. Thanks for showing me this.

Comment: Yea!! You can use `sessionStorage` too for this requirement! :) I will update my answer with explanation.. :)

Comment: Thanks ! I find this really interesting. Just wondering why I never came across it before - must be a well protected secret. ;)

Comment: yes it is.. updated answer!! check and visit the link too if you get more interested.. :)

Answer (score 1):

you can read the query string in JS (you dont have to use PHP for that).

i have used this function before:

```
function GetQueryStringParams(sParam)
{
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
        {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}
```

using localStorage may result it problems in older browsers. if you have to avoid using the query string i suggest that you will use a cookie.

[this should show you how](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Comment: Thanks a lot - this is very helpful too ! For now I will stick with the localStorage approach but voted this one up and will definitely keep it in mind. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
        you can use query string as well for this purpose
        case 'registration successful':     
            $.ajax({        
                type: "post",   
                url: "ajax.php",
                cache: "false",
                data: {
                    node: 'loginUser',
                    email: email,
                    pass: pass
                },
                success: function(data){
                    // redirect to index page
                    window.location.href = baseURL + '/index.php?lang=' + selectedLang+'&msg=true';
                    // after the redirect I would like to show an alert on the targeted index page
                }
            });
            break;
    ---------------------
On index page get value from url
$(document).ready(function(){
    var msg=window.location.toString().Split('msg')[1];
    if(msg)
    {
          alert("Welcome....");
    }
});
```